# bash script debug output + and ++

Tags: shell-script

What are / is the significance of `+` and `++` at the beginning of `bash` debug (`set -x`) output?

The original text looks like this

```
++ delete 
+ exitstatus=0
+ '[' 0 = 0 ']'
++ delete
+ whiptail --title 'Command output 1311' --separate-output --scrolltext --msgbox '/usr/bin/raspi-config-DEBUG.sh: line 1311: delete: command not found' 17 80 10
+ echo '1317  done printing choice to stdout'
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `+` is the `PS4` prompt (just like `PS1` usually holds `$` or some variation thereof, which is the default interactive prompt).  It is outputted before each command executed when tracing is enabled with `set -x`.

The `bash` manual says this:

> `PS4`
>
> The value of this parameter is expanded as with `PS1` and the
>                 value is printed before each command bash displays during an
>                 execution trace.  The first character of `PS4` is replicated
>                 multiple times, as necessary, to indicate multiple levels of
>                 indirection.  The default is `+`.

The multiple `+` that you may see are due to commands being executed in subshells.

Example showing three levels of subshells:

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "$( echo "$( echo hi )" )"
```

```
$ bash -x script.sh
+++ echo hi
++ echo hi
+ echo hi
hi
```

Comment: Great, now for the formatting part - how was it reformatted to look as original text, for future references.

Comment: @JanHus You can't reformat it to get the original shell script back.  In my example, there is no information that tells me exactly what the original commands looked like.